# MySQL Error with Insert/Update on Duplicate Key

Tags: python, mysql

Whats wrong with the following statement?

I'm trying to insert data into my table but update it if there is a duplicate entry - When I run it, I get the following error:

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'updat e temp set impressions = impressions + 1, clicks = clicks
>   + 0, ctr = (ctr +' at line 1")

```
def insert_or_update_new(self, profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute('''insert into temp (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update temp set impressions = impressions + %s, clicks = clicks + %s, ctr = (ctr + %s / 2)''', (profile_id, landing_page, keyword, position, impressions, clicks, ctr, impressions, clicks, ctr))
        self.db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        self.db.rollback()
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        return e
```

Update: Removed duplicate UPDATE - error still there.

Comment: You've duplicated `update update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement should look not like

```
on duplicate key update update temp set impressions...
```

but

```
on duplicate key update impressions=...
```

Comment: You beauty :) Will accept once it allows me to. Any explanation on why this is?

Comment: look at link provided by larwa1n below and there is a syntax you can use :)

Answer (score 0):

Your statement includes the word *update* twice, removing one might do the trick :-)

Comment: Well spotted, however still getting (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set i
mpressions = impressions + 1, clicks = clicks + 0, ctr = (ctr + 0 / 2)' at line 1")

Comment: I think the *set* is also not needed. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html